# OpenCV light vector computation

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get my light vector the math formula is

```
float3 l_ik = p_light - focus / || p_light - focus ||
```

To get the value for `|| p_light - focus ||` is used the `normalize()` function from cv then I tried to simple calculate  A / ||B|| therefore I tried to see the formula as

```
A / B <=> A * B^(-1) 
in c++:
  float3 l_ik = (p_light - focus) * ( normalize(p_light,focus)^(-1))
```

which results to a `no match for 'operator^' in 'math::operator*(...)`. This means there is a no implement for this operator, or what? or is it not possible to calculate vectors ^(-1)

thx for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^ is the 'xor' operator in c++, not what you expected. `pow(some_mat, number);` seems more appropriate

also normalize() is used to make a unit vector, and takes a src and a dst Mat, instead you probably wanted `norm(p_light - focus); // the norm of the diff`

---

(can it be you meant opengl, not opencv ?)

---

[edit]

was pretty blind yesterday, your formula is just the unit-length (p_light - focus) vector, so :

```
Vec3f v = p_light - focus;
Vec3f l_ik = v / norm(v);
```

Comment: of course `pow()`in c++ but there is no `pow(float3, int)` yeah I mean openCV :)

Comment: there's no float3 in opencv as well. but it might work with Vec3f

Comment: later I realized that the `normalize()` function from the framework is `vector v / length(vector v)` seems to be easier. but also works your way. thx